# selecting a row in vba problem

Tags: excel, vba

i am programmatically selecting a row in VBA but it is giving me a TYPE MISMATCH error on this:

```
Rows(Str(i) & ":" & Str(i)).Select
```

what am i doing wrong?

```
For i = 5 To 1000
    If Worksheets("5470").Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
        Rows(Str(i) & ":" & Str(i)).Select
        Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use

```
Rows(i).Select
```

Afaik, rows can be indexed by the row number too.

Alternative:

```
Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Select
```

Answer (score 5):

The error you are getting is because the STR function prepends a space to the number.
So, when i=100, you'll get " 100: 100".
You could the method of GolezTrol, or use cstr() instead of str().
The space is prepended to account for a possible negative value.